# Redux State Change Not Re-rendering with Immutable JS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

When my action successfully excutes and my state is returned, with a change, the child component is not re-rendering. I am using Immutable JS to have immutable state objects.

This is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  sectionsArray: [],
};

export default function seatingChartSections(state = fromJS(initialState), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.LOAD_SEATING_CHART_SECTIONS:
      return fromJS({ sectionsArray: action.seatingChartSections });

    case actionTypes.CLICK_SECTION:
      return state.updateIn(['sectionsArray'], (list) => {
        const index = list.findIndex(item => item.get('_key') === action.section);
        if (list.getIn([index, 'selected']) === true) {
          return list.setIn([index, 'selected'], false);
        }
        return list.setIn([index, 'selected'], true);
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is the parent component:

```
class SeatingChartSections extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.seatingChartSections.sectionsArray.map(section => (<SeatingChartSection
        key={section._key}
        section={section}
        onClick={this.selectSection}
      />))
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    seatingChartSections: state.seatingChartSections.toJS(),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SeatingChartSections);
```

This is the child component:

```
class SeatingChartSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (this.props.section.selected) {
      this.state = {
        fill: '#1aa3ff',
        stroke: '#4d4dff',
      };
    }
    if (!this.props.section.selected) {
      this.state = {
        fill: '#cce6ff',
        stroke: '#4d4dff',
      };
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <polygon
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        id={this.props.section._key}
        fillOpacity={0.4}
        fill={this.state.fill}
        stroke={this.state.stroke}
        points={this.props.section.points}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SeatingChartSection;
```

What do I need to change so that the child is rerendered and the constructor changes this.state.fill?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setState` method to update state.

Replace:

```
this.state = {
    fill: '#cce6ff',
    stroke: '#4d4dff',
};
```

With:

```
this.setState({
    fill: '#cce6ff',
    stroke: '#4d4dff',
});
```

If you take a look at the [State and Lifecycle - Use State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) documentation for react; The first thing listed is:

> Do Not Modify State Directly

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';

// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```